Blocking `idleassetsd` traffic consumes 100%+ CPU on macOS
Its high bandwidth behavior is well-known, but blocking traffic without letting it download anything makes it spin with 120% CPU, and force quitting the app causes it to restart, repeatedly.

launchctl hasn't worked. killall doesn't work, since the process comes back.
Proposed solutions online are largely: unblock idleassetsd traffic, let it download a wallpaper, and then it'll stop spinning up This is ludicrous.

Assets are downloaded somewhere under /System/Library/AssetsV2, so it's possible some data/config is stored there that causes idleassetsd to restart.



What is causing idleassetsd to restart? And now it seems to be starting symptomsd on a regular basis, which is another 50% CPU? How do I stop these?

Also terrible solution: watch sudo killall idleassetsd, with watch installed from homebrew. It seems to restart once every ~10 seconds, with a corresponding spike in CPU usage

I found a way to stop this, but it's entirely unclear what any side effects might be:
cd "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.idleassetsd"
sudo rm [everything]


(Inspired by a script I saw to delete large files in that directory: sudo find "$IDLEASSETSD" -size +5M -delete.)
Note that if you open the Settings app afterwards, it'll re-create Aerial.sqlite.

Oh my God thank you sooooooo much. This bug is driving me nuts
I don't get what the hell Apple is doing about this
They must have tens of thousands, if not hundreds of thousands, if not millions of affected users. I don't get why this doesn't get fixed. That's so painful...
Anyway, thank you guys, you saved my battery life!

I'm trying to automate this script on session login. I came up with this script:
#!/bin/sh
sudo rm -Rf /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.idleassetsd/*
pgrep idleassetsd | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo kill
However I fail to automate it. Would you know how to?

sudo might be difficult during login, look at /etc/sudoers and see if granting password-less sudo will do what you need. note that this is probably overkill/potentially dangerous, providing a specific user or sudo-ing a specific script might be slightly better.

pgrep can also be user-specific, so you might have to look at its flags/permissions to figure something out (man pgrep)

OMG, it has written a terabyte of data in the past few days alone, since doing the cd "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.idleassetsd"; sudo rm -R * - the problem is gone, thank you!!

You can run this command or even add it as a function to your .zshrc or ... .
while true; 
    do
        # Find the process ID of idleassetsd
        pid=$(pgrep idleassetsd)
        
        # If the process is found, kill it with sudo
        if [ ! -z "$pid" ]; then
            echo "Killing idleassetsd (PID: $pid)"
            sudo kill -9 "$pid"
        else
            echo "idleassetsd not running."
        fi
        
        # Wait 1 seconds before checking again
        sleep 1
    done

